# update zend db with multiple where

Tags: php, zend-db

Is something wrong with my query when i am executing getting fatal error.

```
$select = $db->select()
    ->from('test', '*')
    ->where('user_id = ?', 1)
    ->where('url is NULL');
$Details = $db->fetchAll($select);

foreach ($Details as $row1) {
    $PublicId = $row1['public_id'];
    $data = array('password' => $randomString , 'flag' => 1);

    $db->update("test", $data, 'public_id =' . $PublicId);
    $pass = $row1['password']; 
}
```

Error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'wdefabcghbcla45' in 'where clause'' in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #3 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `test` ...', Array) #4 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(634): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `test` ...', Array) #5 D:\Zend Workspace\Test\testDelete.php(39): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('test', Array, 'test_public_id...') #6 {main} Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'wdefabcghbcla45' in 'where clause'' in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Statement\ in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 234

Comment: Could you try to diplay your arrays? For example, it's not clear value of $PublicId, $randomString? Where error do you get?

Comment: i am getting $publicId from query and $randomString from function where i am generating 5 digit random string

Comment: What are their values when you get an error and what type are these fields?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: It looks like you try to use genhjllafkvy6u5 column it where which doesn't exists in table. What line causes an error?

Comment: Could you display the values of variables you use? I think it could clear a lot.

Comment: it is 'wdefabcghbcla45' public id it exists in the database field 'public_id'

Comment: i want to update only rows that i am getting $publicId field from query..

Comment: What line causes error? This one: $db->update( "test", $data, 'public_id ='.$PublicId );
Or does it happen before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
$data = array('password' => $randomString , 'flag' => 1);
$db->update( "test", $data, 'public_id ='.$PublicId );
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your WHERE clause was ending up like `WHERE public_id = wdefabcghbcla45` therefore MySQL was trying "wdefabcghbcla45" as a *column* instead of a *value*. You need to wrap it with quotes (single or double..doesn't matter).

Try it like this:

```
$where = $db->quoteInto('public_id = ?', $PublicId);
$db->update('test', $data, $where);
```

http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting.quote-into

Answer (score 0):

When I tried like this, it worked. Thanks for helping me.

```
$data = array('password' => $randomString , 'flag' => 1);
$where = "public_id = '" . $PublicId."'";
$db->update( "test", $data, $where );
```